# I want to draw an input textfield in typescript which is not static ,it should be dynamic.

Tags: windows

```
<div>
<label>Firstname</label>
<input type="text" name="firstName"></input>
</div>
```

Please help me to draw this dynamically using typescript

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am not sure what you are asking here. Are you using AngularJS ? If you are, do you mean you want to put it in a template? You might read https://stackoverflow.com/help-how-to-ask for some guidance on how to help us to help you

Comment: Thanks for your response Mikel.I am using (ionic2+typescript).I didnt find any solution .Kindly help..

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? All you have provided is some HTML

Comment: That html portion what i have provided that should be draw through typescript file.I want to avoid that static html content.